# How to append a statement using the null coalesce operator to a string?

Tags: php, php-7

I have a string with an operator in:

```
echo 'abc.' . $type ?? 'no type' . 'xyz';
```

If $type exists I want that to be the value, if it does not, I want 'no type' to be the value.

But with the above I just get a $type undefined error. It's not defined in my example as I want 'no type' to be outputted.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: We can start by asking which version of PHP you're using, since `??` is a relatively new operator.

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.

Comment: Please also update your question to mention that. No one should have to read a comment thread to answer your question =) Also, did you make sure to read through the operator precedence list? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php (specifically, you want to look at which of `.` and `??` gets to go first)

Answer (score 9):

You need to add brackets round the ?? operator...

```
echo 'abc.' . ($type ?? 'no type') . 'xyz';
```

What it was doing was evaluating it like `'abc.' . $type` and then `??`.

This is all about [operator precedence](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) (thanks to @Blackhole for the prompt).

Comment: A [link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Null Coalescing Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary):

```
echo 'abc.' . ($type ?? 'no type') . 'xyz';
```

or this ([ternary operator](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator))

```
echo 'abc.' . (isset($type) ? $type : 'no type' ) . 'xyz';
```

Comment: That's not really a userful answer in this case, though. Using `??` is fine, but `.` has higher precedence, so the `??` expression needs to be in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use concatenation when using [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). It can take multiple arguments, just separate them with a comma (as if it were an actual function):

```
echo 'abc.', $type ?? 'no type', 'xyz';
```

This is also (slightly) more efficient than the upvoted answer, especially with long strings (PHP doesn't have to construct/store the whole string in a buffer before displaying it).